# Drive with SQL binaries out of space

Tags: sql-server, performance, disk-space

What happens if the drive (not C-drive) where the SQL binaries are located runs out of space?
Can this take down a production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The SQL error logs are on that drive.